# Can i get an image selected by the user in a conversation with an iMessages app extension?

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I want to create an app that gets an image from a conversation, edits it and sends it back as a reply.
I've done some research and read the I messages framework, and there are a few methods that i think i could use like:

- **didReceive(_:conversation:)**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessagesappviewcontroller/1649189-didreceive
**-

- **didSelect(_:conversation:)**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessagesappviewcontroller/1833298-didselect

- **Instance Property: selectedMessage**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation/1648186-selectedmessage

But i dont fully understand how they work yet or if you can access the image of a received Message by using them.